# Derivation of Truncated Derivatives in Hochreiter's original LSTM Paper

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, backpropagation, derivative, truncation

I was trying to understand the derivation of the truncated derivatives in Hochreiter's origin LSTM paper. Spent a bunch of time without avail. I suppose I am missing a way to map my intuition of truncation to the actual equations.

The following is a snippet from the paper.

I wanted to understand the derivation of the truncated derivative for the output unit. If someone has some notes or a good explanation, would be super helpful!

[image]